# Is it possible to use XNA 3.1 on the ZuneHD and save data to the filesystem?

Tags: xna, zune, zune-hd

If it is possible, how would you go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible so use XNA 3.1 on the ZuneHD, you just have to have XNA 3.1 installed and then the 3.1 Zune Extenstions.

You can read about those on the XNA Team Blog where they made the announcement originally.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xna/archive/2009/09/15/xna-game-studio-3-1-zune-extensions.aspx

For saving data, it works the same as it does on the Xbox 360 so any tutorial sample for that would work the same for the Zune (as long as you're looking at XNA 3.1 samples/tutorials)